# Ionic sending Parse push notification with attached url

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I've been busy with a new application based on ionic. It's a new environment so I have a lot to explore.

I'd walked into some problems and search over the whole internet to find a solution and couldn't find one solving my problem. So I hope one of you guys know a solution.

**I am trying to send notifications to my device using parse. That works fine, but now I want to send an uri attached with it, so that I can open a specific page clicking on the notification that has been recievied. 
The problem is that I have no clue how to correctly send an attached uri and recieve that uri on the device to do something with it.**

I hope some of you knows a solution.

I'm using ASP.NET to send the notification with a working initialized client.

```
var parsePush = new ParsePush();


                // sending to all with your own data
                parsePush.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"alert", txtMessage.Text},// this is replacement for parsePush.Alert                   
                    {"sound", "notify.caf"},// for ios
                    {"badge", "Increment"}// for ios notification count increment on icon
                    //{"category", "http://google.nl" }
                };
                parsePush.SendAsync().Wait();
```

For the ionic side I don't have an event to recieve the notification and work with it. I just get the notification and get redirected to the home page of the app.

Please inform me if there are unclear details.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by searching over the whole internet.

The first thing I did was uncommenthing the category in my parsePush.data on the server side (see code in the question). In the category I define the uri. The next thing I did was adding "ParsePushPlugin.on" to my app.js. Those event are used when a notification is recieved or opened.

I added this code to my app.js inside the .run -> $ionicPlatform.ready.

```
ParsePushPlugin.getInstallationId(function (id) {
        alert(id);
        storage.set('parseId', id);
    }, function (e) {
        alert('error');
    });

    ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN', function (pn) {
        alert('yo i got this push notification:' + JSON.stringify(pn));
    });

    //customEvt can be any string of your choosing, i.e., chat, system, upvote, etc.
    ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN:chat', function (pn) {
        alert('yo i can also use custom event to keep things like chat modularized');
    });

    ParsePushPlugin.on('openPN', function (pn) {
        //you can do things like navigating to a different view here
        //alert('Yo, I get this when the user clicks open a notification from the tray');
        $state.go(pn.category)
    });
```

As you can see "ParsePushPlugin.on('openPn')" has pn as parameters which contains all the data from the recieved and opened notification. This notification also contains the "category (uri)" which is passed from the server side.